# Angular routing for POST URLs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

The tutorial on Angular's website for Routing and Multiple Views shows an example where one partial page has snippets like:

```
<a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
```

It means, when the URL is hit, the route configured for it will be executed and the view will be replaced:

```
when('/phones/:phoneId', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
    controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
}).
```

Here, the params are available in the URL. So they can be used by the `PhoneDetailCtrl from $routeParams`.

But what if the parameters are typed in `SELECT, INPUT` boxes, by the user? How will the `PhoneDetailCtrl` get hold of them?

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: Does not make sense. In Angular HTML is loaded with get, and data is posted using ajax `$http` and `$resource`. Can you explain with a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer:

I think you just need to set up some data binding between your search box and the URL?

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('YourModule').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/phones/:searchValue', {
        templateUrl: 'phoneSearch.html',
        controller: PhoneSearchCntl
    });
});

function PhoneSearchCntl($scope, $routeParams){
    // Get the previous searchValue from the URL or set an empty string.
    $scope.searchValue = $routeParams.searchValue || '';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="PhoneSearchCntl">
    <!-- text input is bound to `searchValue` on the controller. -->
    <input type="text" id="search" ng-model="searchValue"></input>
    
    <!-- The URL of the link is also bound to `searchValue` on the controller. -->
    <a ng-href="#/phones/{{searchValue}}">Search URL</a>
</div>
```

---

### Original answer:

The parameters are made available in the `$routeParams` provider.

Have a look at the [route example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route#example) in the Angular documentation.

Here is a quick summary of how you can use it:

```
angular.module('YourModule').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
        templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
        controller: ChapterCntl
    });
});

function ChapterCntl($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.name = "ChapterCntl";
    $scope.params = $routeParams;
}
```

So a URL like this: `/Book/Moby/ch/1` will have the following properties in the `$routeParams`:

```
$routeParams = {"bookId":"Moby","chapterId":"1"}
```

Comment: In your case again, you have a URL: /Book/Moby/ch/1. What it on your UI you had a Search box? The text typed by the user needs to go to the controller and a search needs to be performed. Where will the Search text be available to the controller?

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer, but I'm not exactly sure I'm understanding your question properly. Are you asking how to post the search query back to a server to do the actual searching?

Comment: Now let us imagine, instead of a Search box, there are about 20 different fields that accept the user's profile data. Do we need to construct a URL of 20 fields.

Comment: Yes, if that's how much data you have. Or you can encode it in JSON or XML or some kind of transport format to send it off to the server.